# Matrix norm definition with constraint

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms

I know that the p-norm of a matrix is defined as:

$\displaystyle \|A\|_p = \max_{x\neq0}\frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p}$

However, how can I conclude the below formula from the above formula?

$\|A\|_p=\max_{\|x\|_p = 1} \|Ax\|_p$

Comment: "below formula" doesn't look a formula: there's no equal sign.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\neq0$, then $x$ can be written as $x = \alpha u$  where $\|u\|_p = 1$ and $\alpha = \|x\|_p\neq 0$. The matrix norm is then
$$
\|A\|_p = \max_{x\neq 0} \frac{\|Ax\|_p}{\|x\|_p} = \max_{\|u\|_p=1} \frac{\|A(\alpha u)\|_p}{\|\alpha u\|_p} = \max_{\|u\|_p=1} \frac{|\alpha|\|Au\|_p}{|\alpha|\|u\|_p} = \max_{\|u\|_p=1} \frac{\|Au\|_p}{\| u\|_p} = \max_{\|u\|_p=1} \|Au\|_p.
$$